# How to set controls in a screen to fit for all resolutions in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

AnyOne please tell me how to design the screen to fit for all resolutions.
there are different resolutions screen in windows 8.Any 9 patch work need to do or solution to this .please tell me the solution for this?
How to write the code for that ?

Answer (score 1):

Your UI must be designed to scale dynamically based on the resolution of the screen.

The technical details are available in the following quickstart: [Defining layouts using C#/VB/C++ and XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh465337.aspx) (here is the [JavaScript and HTML version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465343.aspx)).

You should also read the following blog post from Building Windows 8: [Scaling to different screens](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/03/21/scaling-to-different-screens.aspx). It gives a lot of background information.